# Whats the difference between babel-preset-es2015 and babel-preset-env?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm currently trying to understand about babel configuration, but got confused by `babel-preset-**`, there are many preset in babel, like `env`, `es2015`, `react` and others, I do understand that `babel-preset-es2015` is needed to transpile es2015 code to previous js code so it can be understood by most/older browser, what about `babel-preset-env`?

What are the differences between those presets? Can one use `env` without using `es2015` or vice versa? and what are the cases when we need those two presets to be present on our project build system?

Thank You.

Comment: babel themselves recommend using `babel-preset-env` now.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/env/

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `babel-preset-es20XX` (15, 16, 17) presets include transforms needed to convert features added in that specific year to code that is compatible with the previous version.

`babel-preset-env` includes transforms for all features that have landed in the spec, but only enables the ones needed to make the features work based on the set of environments you've provided to it. If you pass no options to `env` it essentially works like `es2015, es2016, es2017` all together.

`babel-preset-react` is the set of transformations needed to convert React/Facebook-related syntax extensions like Flowtype and React's JSX.

Comment: Does `babel-preset-env` also change the minification process from UglifyJS to babili? I'm slightly confused by it.

Comment: It does not. How minification is done is separate. `preset-env` may make your output code ES6 though, and standard Uglify cannot handle ES6, so if you use `env` with `uglify` you should use the `uglify` target: https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env#targetsuglify